# Cannot resolve symbol 'xhtml.div.type' in custom xml schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xhtml

I am struggling to reuse some XHTML schema definitions. I want to define a custom type for a subset of XHTML (div in this case) so i can declare elements of that custom xhtml type later on. For that, i have an schema like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema id="story" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           targetNamespace="https://example.com"
           xmlns="https://example.com"
           xmlns:tns="https://example.com"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:xh11blk="https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml-blkstruct-1.xsd"
>
    <xs:import namespace="https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml-blkstruct-1.xsd"
        schemaLocation="https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml-blkstruct-1.xsd"/>

    <xs:complexType mixed="true" name="CustomXHTML">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="xh11blk:xhtml.div.type"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

with this in place i constantly receive errors from IDEs

- IntelliJ: Cannot resolve symbol 'xh11blk:xhtml.div.type'
- oXygen:   Cannot resolve the name 'xh11blk:xhtml.div.type' to a(n) 'type definition' component.

What am i missing here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the referenced/imported schema set a targetNamespace at all? While in the Microsoft world some tools make the namespace the URL of the schema file I doubt that W3C specs do that. If you want to reuse XHTML why does your import refer to some namespace that is not the XHTML namespace?

Comment: The referenced imported schema does not set a namespace. Regarding referencing the namespace that is not xhtml i can only say i did it without any reason, came out of ignorance :)

Comment: I think, with XSD 1.0, to use a schema that does not set a target namespace for elements in the target namespace you want, you need to use `xs:redefine`. But the whole modular approach there for XHTML 1.1 is rather complex, I think you need to include and/or redefine various other modules to be able to use that div type.

Comment: thanks for your comments. I thought it was going to be a simpler task. In that case, i probably will end up redefining myself a small subset of the grammar.